# 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) on Windows 8.1 Store app while replacing/opening a hidden file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm getting "`Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`" error when I'm trying to replace an existing hidden file. I cannot put conditions to check the attributes, as this file may or may not be hidden at times. here is the code snippent i'm using:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim slimWrite = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 1);
public void CreateFile(string fileName, string content)
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    try
    {
        slimWrite.WaitAsync();
        var localFolderTask = storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(dirName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        localFolderTask.AsTask().Wait(timeout); //timeout = 10000
        if (localFolderTask.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
        {
            var localFolder = localFolderTask.GetResults();
            if (localFolder != null)
            {
                var fileTask = localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                fileTask.AsTask().Wait(timeout);
                if (fileTask.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
                {
                    var file = fileTask.GetResults();
                    var writeTask = FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, content);
                    writeTask.AsTask().Wait(timeout);
                    if (writeTask.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
                        {//Job complete; write to cache}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { Log here... }
    finally
    {
        slimWrite.Release();
    }
}
```

the error is raised by the `CreateFileAsync(...)` line. Did anyone faced similar problems with Windows 8.1 Store projects?

**EDIT:** The same error occurs when I'm opening (GetFileAsync()) a hidden file too!

Comment: Do you have this with normal files as well? How are these files created?

Comment: Normal files gets created/replaced as expected. The problematic case is only with the hidden files. This hidden file is not created by the application, but somehow; while deployment one of the file is getting hidden and due to which the file is irreplaceable from the app

Comment: Did you have any luck in solving this? I have the same problem but for the Special Folder "AppData", which is a hidden folder.

Comment: Nope! We wrote a script to clear the hidden/read only files at the deployment time. The app's lifetime also got over; so didn't get a proper solution to work on.